# Gateway Issue - "ping" works, "curl" not

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, nat, gateway

We have a *[S]SRV_GATEWAY* server with two NICs (*[I]WAN/INT_LAN* and *[I]PRIV_LAN*) configured as GATEWAY, DNS and DHCP for a private network (*[N]PRIV_LAN*).

The server *[S]SRV_GATEWAY* accesses the internet (it consumes itself as DNS) and all other servers (*[S]PRIV_SRV_X*) consume the DHCP, DNS and GATEWAY provided by the server *[S]SRV_GATEWAY*.

- **Network layout...**

```
                     [N]WAN/INT_LAN (10.2.0.0/24)
                      ↕
                     [I]WAN/INT_LAN
                  [S]SRV_GATEWAY
                     [I]PRIV_LAN
                      ↕
                     [N]PRIV_LAN (10.3.0.0/24)
                      ↕
       ...............................
       ↕              ↕              ↕
      [S]PRIV_SRV_0  [S]PRIV_SRV_1  [S]PRIV_SRV_0
                     [S]PRIV_SRV_2  [S]PRIV_SRV_0
                     [S]PRIV_SRV_3
    
     _ [N] - Network;
     _ [I] - Network Interface;
     _ [S] - Server.
    
     _ [N]WAN/INT_LAN - Has internet access;
     _ [N]PRIV_LAN - Private network.
```

---

**QUESTION:** Why we can successfully `ping` servers on the internet and can't access the same servers using `curl` on the server *[S]PRIV_SRV_0* (see output below)?

```
    [root@okd4-bootstrap core]# ping -c 2 www.google.com
    PING www.google.com (172.217.18.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from ham02s14-in-f196.1e100.net (172.217.18.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=10.5 ms
    64 bytes from par10s38-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=10.6 ms
    
    --- www.google.com ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.500/10.548/10.597/0.048 ms

    [root@okd4-bootstrap core]# curl http://www.google.com
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.google.com port 80: No route to host
```

---

**EXTRA:**

- **How *SRV_GATEWAY* was set to be GATEWAY:**

The server *SRV_GATEWAY* has been configured as GATEWAY through commands...

Enable *IP forwarding*...

```
tee "/etc/sysctl.d/ip_forward.conf" << EOF
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
EOF
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Setup an outbound NAT gateway with destination on NIC ens3 (*[I]WAN/INT_LAN*) masking devices configured in CIDR 10.3.0.0/24...

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE -s 10.3.0.0/24
firewall-cmd --reload
```

- **Some information obtained from the server *[S]PRIV_SRV_0*:**

```
[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -i '^nameserver' | head -n1 | cut -d ' ' -f2
10.3.0.14

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# ip r
default via 10.3.0.14 dev ens3 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.3.0.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.0.4 metric 100 

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.0.14       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens3
10.3.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens3

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# netstat -r -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.0.14       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens3
10.3.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens3

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=10.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=11.0 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.769/10.891/11.013/0.122 ms

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 10.3.0.14
search okd.local

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# tracepath 8.8.8.8
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  api-int.mbr.okd.local                                 0.526ms 
 1:  api-int.mbr.okd.local                                 0.855ms 
 2:  okd4-services.okd.local                               1.842ms !H
     Resume: pmtu 1500 

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# tracepath www.google.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  api.mbr.okd.local                                     0.481ms 
 1:  api-int.mbr.okd.local                                 0.562ms 
 2:  api.mbr.okd.local                                     0.553ms !H
     Resume: pmtu 1500 

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# ip route show
default via 10.3.0.14 dev ens3 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.3.0.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.0.4 metric 100 

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# nslookup www.google.com
Server:         10.3.0.14
Address:        10.3.0.14#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.217.18.196
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4007:805::2004

[root@okd4-bootstrap core]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

**Thanks! =D**

Comment: Do the server's firewalld rules allow forwarding?

Comment: @user1686 You talk about this "Enable IP forwarding..." (see post)? Thanks! =D

Comment: No, I'm asking about whether your _firewall rules_ allow forwarding. Like the 'FORWARD' chain in iptables.

Comment: Ow! Sorry, no. =D I believe you are talking about this https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_Stream_8&p=firewalld&f=2 (see last 2 lines of example 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @user1686...

> I'm asking about whether your firewall rules allow forwarding. Like
> the 'FORWARD' chain in iptables.

... were missing rules regarding ***FORWARD***.

However other than that, was necessary add/enable the ***masquerade*** rule.

---

**COMPLETE SOLUTION:**

Enable IP forwarding...

```
tee "/etc/sysctl.d/ip_forward.conf" << EOF
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
EOF
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Add rules to firewall (*firewall-cmd*)...

Model

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone public --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o [WAN_NIC] -j MASQUERADE
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i [LAN_NIC] -o [WAN_NIC] -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i [WAN_NIC] -o [LAN_NIC] -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Example

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone public --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i ens4 -o ens3 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i ens3 -o ens4 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --reload
```

**IMPORTANT:** Several examples on the internet recommend placing the *[WAN_NIC]* and *[LAN_NIC]* interfaces in different zones (*external* and *internal*) as shown here...

```
firewall-cmd --add-interface [WAN_NIC] --zone external
firewall-cmd --add-interface [LAN_NIC] --zone internal
```

... , however I don't want to worry about zones since all my firewall rules are in the default *public* zone. Thus, it is not necessary to define zones for this scheme to work, everything can be left in the *public* zone.

**Thanks! =D**

**[Ref(s).:** https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_Stream_8&p=firewalld&f=2 ,
https://www.comdivision.com/blog/centos-7-nat-router-basic-configuration ,
https://blog.redbranch.net/2015/07/30/centos-7-as-nat-gateway-for-private-network/ .
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/550064/61742 ,
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=53819#p227743 ,
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=firewalld&f=2 ,
https://serverfault.com/q/870902/276753 **]**